# Selenium RC testing: Internet Explorer opens twice

Tags: internet-explorer, selenium-rc

I am running my Selenium RC tests in IE7. The problem is that when I start tests, Selenium opens two windows instead of one: the portal I'm testing doesn't open in the first one, but it opens correctly in the second.

The problem is that it fails with an error in method openPortal() [and lets me know that it was not possible to open portal], which shouldn't happened, as far as the portal opens, as I just said.

Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem came from IE configurations. 
I solved the problem adding the portal I was testing into Trusted sites and afterward everything went on ok.

Answer (score 0):

Something I found on my computer which may help. In you browser window, go to "tools", scroll down to "manage add ons", click "toolbars & extensions", look at the list to the right of it. Scroll down until you see Java, & disable it. Then look at find "JQSIEStartDetector Impl Class" & disable it. You will notice it has the exact same publisher and file date & time as the Java. This solved the problem on my pc.